# how to use pointers in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers

I have seen some iOS developpers using code like this :

```
- (void)setupWebView:(UIWebView**)aWebView {
 UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
.....

 if (*aWebView) {
        [*aWebView release];
    }

    *aWebView = webview;
}
```

Do you know what'is this mean and why we use this ? thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with C or C++? It's Objective-C!

Comment: because i have never see it in objective c !!!

Comment: @SamirGuerdah: It's important to remember that Objective-C is a strict superset of C. Anything valid in C is valid in Objective-C. I've written plenty of code like this when interfacing with a strict C module.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
- (void)setupWebView:(UIWebView**)aWebView {
```

That is awful.   You should **never** have a method that returns void, but sets an argument by reference unless:

• there are multiple arguments set

• the method is prefixed with `get`

That method should simply return the created instance directly.   And this just makes it worse -- is flat out wrong:

```
 if (*aWebView) {
    [*aWebView release];
 }

 *aWebView = webview;
```

1. it breaks encapsulation;  what if the caller passed a reference to an iVar slot.  Now you have the callee managing the callers memory which is both horrible practice and quite likely crashy (in the face of concurrency, for example).
2. it'll crash if `aWebView` is NULL;  crash on the assignment, specifically.
3. if `aWebView` refers to an iVar slot, it bypasses any possible property use (a different way of breaking encapsulation).

Answer (score 2):

It is a method to initialize a pointer.  The first line allocates the object.  The if statement makes sure that the passed in pointer-to-a-pointer is not already allocated, if it is it releases it. then it sets the referenced pointer to the newly allocated object.

Comment: "good practice" is subjective. If you are looking for a reason to nail a coder you don't like I would say find something else, it's a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: do not do this in Objective-C. Outside of NSError you never really code this way ever.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @bbum is probably correct, but leaves out one aspect to the question that I see there. There are many examples in Foundation which use pointer-pointers in the method signature, so you can say it is a common pattern. And those are probably not a beginners mistake.

Most of these examples are similar in that they fall into one category: the API tries to avoid the usages of exceptions, and instead use `NSError` for failures. But because the return value is used for a `BOOL` that signals success, an `NSError` pointer-pointer is used as output parameter. Only in the probably rare error case an `NSError` object is created, which can contain error code and error descriptions, and localized descriptions and possibly even more information (like an array of multiple errors in the case of bulk operations). So the main success case is efficient, and the error case has some power to communicate what went wrong, without resorting to exceptions. That is the justification behind these signatures as I understand it.

You can find examples of this usage in both `NSFileManager` and `NSManagedObjectContext`.

One might be tempted to use pointer-pointers in other cases where you want multiple return values and an array does not make sense (e.g. because the values are not of same type), but as @bbum said, it is likely better to look hard for alternatives.

Comment: “… the API tries to avoid the usages of exceptions…” More precisely, the API uses exceptions for programmer mistakes, and errors for input bogosity and other run-time problems. For example, `[myArray objectAtIndex:[myArray count]]` will cause an exception (what you said doesn't make sense), but `BOOL successfullyDeleted = [myFileMgr removeItemAtURL:myURLToAFileThatDoesntExist error:&error]` will return `NO` and an error (what you said makes sense but can't be done).

Comment: This doesn't make pointer-pointers common, it makes pointer-pointers for the purpose of optionally providing error details common.  Big difference.   And, as Peter says, it isn't about "avoiding" exceptions, it is that exceptions are *not* recoverable whereas use of NSError is intended to be recoverable.

Comment: @bbum this is very well about avoiding exceptions. I didn't say for which reason, but that doesn't make it wrong. Do you want to argue or do you want to answer questions? Btw. I didn't say "probably correct" wrt to your answer to annoy you, but to indicate that I'm don't want to make a final call on that. What kind of usage makes pointer-pointers "common" is probably something that can't be answered without qualifying "common" a bit more.

Comment: Note that I didn't downvote;  my point was that because a single specific pattern is used commonly, it does not make the generic form of the pattern common.  As it stands, the use of pointer-pointers should be exceedingly rare and limited to very specific roles; NSError** and multiple return values with a `get` prefix. As for exceptions, the NSError pattern is for recoverable errors, exceptions are thrown for unrecoverable errors.  The two are entirely orthogonal in their roles within the APIs.

Comment: Fair enough. It is quite common to write client code for CoreData or file system API that is sprinkled with pointer-pointer methods, NSError local variables that you need to nil out before use, and pass with address-of operator, enough to make a smart person wonder what kind of circumstances would give justification to adopt that style in your own APIs. I meant "common" to be understood in that sense.

Comment: I am admittedly pedantic, but after 23 years of programming against the Cocoa APIs, I've found that precision in language and intent goes along way to facilitating learning and, eventually, success.  BTW:  There is no need -- no purpose to -- assigning `nil` to the local `NSError` variable.